# How to make out if a url is called from uiwebview

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ios, uiwebview

I am working on a project which can be called from the browser also on load of a iOS app. The app has a `UIWebView` which links to my website. I want to find out if a particular user has logged in into the website from the app using PHP.

Please help me with this and let me know how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that first of all you are trying to find a way as how check whether a url is called and perform some actions based on that URL.

In that case make use of the delegate methods for UIWebview to find out which URL is being called,

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
       NSLog(@"Loading URL :%@",request.URL.absoluteString);
       //This logs out the webview URL while it starts loading
 }
```

Then, inside `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method check the corresponding URL, like,

```
if ([[[yourWebViewInstance.request URL] absoluteString] isEqualToString:URL_You_Want_to_Check])
{
         //Prints the whole HTML souce content of the page that is loaded
      DLog(@"document.documentElement.outerHTML %@",yourHTMLSourceCodeString);
        //Perform any other operation
}
```

Else you can also make use of `webViewDidStartLoad:` method which will be called prior to `webViewDidFinishLoad:` based on your requirement.

Comment: Is it possible to detect in the php page if the call is from the app ?

Comment: I guess your php page will be contained inside an HTML body once you load that webpage (Web View). In the above method `webViewDidFinishLoad:` print the html content and parse through it... It can be done . But I feel its a little cumbersome. To check whether the call is from app on your php you need to set some flag and respective logic which you'll be modifying both from app and web side

Comment: Can I do it using the user agent?
I found something to be done in javascript, can you please tell me how to use it in php,

var is_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Version)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

Comment: Sorry I have never tried using AppleWeb Kit and No idea WRT web development. But what I suggest you is to parse the html tag content and inside which go to the particular PHP Function which you want...